# Save QR scan results in my Android application

Tags: android, qr-code

I am developing an app for scanning QR codes. I used the ZBar library to scan QR codes, and it works properly.

When I run the app & scan the QR code, I get all the details of that QR image below the screen. Now my issue is that I want to store that details into my app as a history. Because when I scan a lot many QR images, and I want to check which QR image is to be scanned, or after moving out from the exhibition I want to know the cost of any QR image, I can check it when I can have a history button where all the QR images' data will be stored.

Comment: Your are explaining what you want to do, but... What is your question/problem?

Comment: Also, try looking into Zebra Crossing (ZXing) and their Barcode scanner application.

Comment: Pablo Lozana : my app is ready... now my problem is i want to store the QR image details ...naming the button as a history...after clicking the history i should get all the details till date whenever i have scan..

Comment: Razgriz: my app is already ready using ZBar library and i want to use the same library & implement..

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use SQLite db. Insert new row on completed scan, select names of last n rows when displaying history, select one full row to display details.

More on SQLite dbs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

Other storage options are also described there. You can save all data into file, but you have to handle storing/parsing values yourself.

Comment: Sorry, you didn't provide any code so I don't know the structure of data you want to store. In your history activity, you would use ListView with CursorAdaper and SQLiteCursor to display list of saved details.

Comment: Just post the code in the question so others can help and benefit from the answers. I'm sorry but I don't do private consulting over email.